# R check if list of lists contains specific list

Tags: r, list

There are three lists:

```
a = list(1,2)
b = list(2,3)
c = list(a,b)
```

The command `a %in% c` yields `FALSE FALSE`. The result I would like to see is `TRUE` since a is an element of list c. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether each component is identical to `a` and return TRUE if any of those comparisons are TRUE.

```
any(sapply(c, identical, a))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: this is way more efficient than Poza's solution.

Answer (score 2):

This should also help:

```
list(a) %in% c
```

Examples:

```
a = list(1,2)
b = list(2,3)
c = list(a,b)
y = list(3,4)
z = list(1)


list(a) %in% c  # True
list(b) %in% c  # True
list(y) %in% c  # False
list(z) %in% c  # False
```